# Pyinstaller import error: zope.interface not found

Tags: python, twisted, pyinstaller, zope.interface

I am trying to create standalone exe of twisted application using PyInstaller. Everything is ok, even executable file is getting build, but its not working. I mean if try to execute it gives error 'Import error: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface."

I already have installed zope.interface 4.1.0. Also twisted application is running fine, with 'python ' But at the time of building executable file Pyinstaller is unble to import zope.interface.

How to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

finally problem solved.
Problem is zope.interface is not getting added in PYTHONPATH.
Actually I have tried different setups (like pip & exe), though it was not getting added. Exact reason I don't know.
But after installing zope.interface using 'easy_install ', it is added in PYTHONPATH & I am able to create executable file.

Thank you for taking interest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll help in your problem: http://github.com/kpdyer/fteproxy/issues/66